# c++ global config class without passing as reference

Tags: c++, class, global

I have my Config class, that manages app config, get set etc.
I want other classes to be able to use it, but  passing it to each method as a reference is a pain, And I have a feeling there is better way to do it.

so this is my config class header:

```
class Config
{
public:
    Config();

public:
    char *port;

    template <class Type = std::string>
    Type get(std::string value)
    {
        return _config.get<Type>(value);
    };
    void set(std::string key,std::string value){
        _config.put(key,value);
        boost::property_tree::json_parser::write_json("config.json",_config);
    };
    std::string getConfig()
    {
        std::stringstream buffer;
        boost::property_tree::json_parser::write_json(buffer, _config);
        return buffer.str();
    };
    bool valid = false;

private:
    boost::property_tree::ptree _config;
};
```

I have seen some macros, not sure if that's correct approach besides I don't know how to use it yet.

Comment: Can you pass a reference to the config class in the other class constructors, and then save that in each class as a data member?

Comment: Passing dependencies explicitly is good design, I would not change that. I wonder why you need to pass it to each method though, wouldn't you give it to the constructor of the using classes? Seeing how you use those settings would probably be interesting.

Comment: Probably not all other classes needs Config class instance, but most of them. Kind of seems like passing them to constructors and saving them in each class, is not right. But I might be wrong. I just need to read and write config from different classes. No other magic

Comment: Also I need same instance in all of those classes. As it's being changed dynamically

Comment: I think I will actually stick to passing it to each constructor I need it in. Seems like the most controllable option

Comment: Also it is a good idea to have a virtual configuration class. So you can mock it in your automatic tests and change the implementation if needed (for example use method of storing info other than boost::ptree).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the actual usage context, but if you are familiar with the singleton pattern, this might be a way to go here in doubt if you are not able to forward the configuration information by design in a quite non-intrusive way (the latter should almost always be the preferred way but I know there are sometimes exceptional situations in reality). The context of the singleton needn't to be totally global in doubt since you can use a global singleton to ensure more "context-sensitive" branching if required.

But as mentioned: Try to solve this by design if the context of this configuration isn't that global in doubt. Provide a possibly quite central handler class (as sharedPtr for instance) that offers the configuration data on request. Then, solely the used objects' constructors require that one as a parameter.

Comment: Singleton is never a solution. Eventually you'll realize that in some places you want a different configuration. Or that you wanted to have unit tests for your code. And then you'll wish you never used singletons. Singletons are workarounds at best when you lack time for refactoring to a better design.

Comment: Hm and that's why, Scott Meyers for instance explains them in various books and articles? Singletons are very controversially discussed for sure, but there are definitively cases where they are really required at least due to ratio assessments. Additionally if you read my answer carefully, you should realize that I doubt too, that this is the most robust solution here.

Comment: @spectras PS: "Singleton is never a solution." Please don't make subjective opinions to objective facts. You're right, that they are often not recommended for good reasons. But ratio assessment is one often underestimated principle of software development and for several minor projects, the real perfect design solution - if existent - might require disproportional resources in doubt (where you can make things worse and error prone too if not done carefully).

Comment: When you come to a website that gathers experts, you come to it to get experts' advice and experience. If we were limiting the website to purely objective facts, stackoverflow would be merely an index to other authoritative resources. — and here, encouraging someone who has a good and working design to replace it with a singleton is nonsense, even with the disclaimers.

Comment: I encouraged nobody to replace a working good design with a worse one. The OP's question was about approaches that limit excessive parameter forwarding. In some rare cases, singletons can be a way to go here and it fully depends on the context in doubt if applicable. I stated it for completeness in the first place. Furthermore, there are dozends of robust hybrid solutions that reduce the drawbacks of full global singletons by far. Philosophical discussions about the pattern/anti-pattern quality of the singleton concept are off-topic further on.